# Loop in torch seems much slower than it should be

Tags: lua, deep-learning, luajit, torch

I've the following piece of code

```
for i=1,A do
    for j=1,B do
        self.gradInput:narrow(1, self.C[i][j], 1):add(gradOutput[2][i][j])
    end
end
```

in a custom module in torch.

For values of A = 18K, B=30, this loop is taking ~4 s (measured using torch.Timer) which seems extremely high to me.

For context, C is a FloatTensor of size (A, B) and gradOutput of (2, A, B). The processor is AMD Opteron 4386 having 16 cores each with cache size 2MB.

So, it seems to me that C, gradOutput, gradInput should already be cached so 4s for such a short loop seems insanely high to me.

Anyone have any ideas why it's so slow and if/how I can improve the performance?

Comment: Lua uses only one CPU core.  `A*B` is more that half million, so FloatTensor of size (A,B) does not fit in 2 MB cache.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff It mostly does though -- it's (18K*30*4)  which is 2109 KB for each matrix (and there are 3 of those) so so only a few calls to the main memory (each taking say 200 ns) should do it.

Comment: Access to your data is sequential, so after one full round all your array elements will be cached-in and then evicted-out.  Your "safe limit" is about 1 MB.